# where is .appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java exist in GAE Project

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

Hi I want to delete the **.appcfg_oauth2_token_java**  but i am not  able to search in using the eclipse.  Can anyone please help me to find it  how can i get it.

Comment: .appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java file found in the home directory for example my  HOME directory is c:/user/prabhat .  you will get .appcfg_oauth2_token_java  there.

Answer (score 0):

You  can find the .appcfg_oauth_token_java file in your home directory. you can get more detail  using  [This](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Passwordless_Login_with_OAuth2)